# Adoptable storage not show as FAT32 on PC

Tags: android

My 32GB sd card is formatted as a adoptable storage on samsung j5. but when i connect the sd into my windows laptop through a card reader it shows as fat32 and the chip is empty. but it is half full on my phone. Please can anyone help me to understand why this happening?

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to superuser.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you adopt an SD card on Android it's reformatted with an encrypted Linux filesystem and is readable only on the Android device where it was adopted. You cannot see any contents of the card on any other device and if you wish to use it on another device you need to reformat the card first.